# jQuery - property not supported

Tags: javascript, jquery

Getting a message from jQuery:

> JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method
>   'valid'

My code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#formName').validate();
    // more jQuery functions
    // then:
    $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var result = $('#formName').valid();
        alert(result);
    });
});
```

I have the following jQuery Libraries and plugins included in my code:

```
<script type="text/jscript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")"></script>
<script type="text/jscript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive-ajax.js")"></script>
```

Anyone run into this before?  Do I need a more recent version of jQuery?  What's up here?  ALso worth noting.... this is a site built using Telerik's 'Kendo' addins.

Comment: Will you put your code in a jsfiddle?

Comment: What is `text/jscript`?

Comment: The code works perfectly fine by itself (given that your script is loaded **AFTER** the jQuery and the validation script): http://jsfiddle.net/9hH2V/

Answer (score 0):

Well the low hanging fruit answer would be your the script containing your $(document).ready() function is loading before the actual jquery script.

I would suggest monitoring the http request via fiddler or built int network debugger (if available) to see what order your scripts are loading in.

jQuery should load first.